# How to get data from an int pointer to a memory stream in c#?

Tags: c#, pointers, tiff, memorystream

I am using an API and a method does something to store an image into a memory stream, but the returned values from that method are an Integer pointer to the memory stream and a size value. Does c# support C style memory manipulation using pointers?

How can I get the Image from the memory pointer and save it to a filestream or save as file? Can some one please refer any pointers on this ?

Comment: Pretty unlikely that, if you know the code uses a stream, that what you get back is actually an int*.  Much more likely is an interface pointer, like IStream*.  We can only guess at it.  Ask the vendor, they *know*.

Comment: @HansPassant you were right, it was a pointer returned, no idea why they return an Integer instead. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read the memory stream like this:

```
using (System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream memoryStream = new UnmanagedMemoryStream(pointer, length, length, FileAccess.Read))
{
    byte[] imageBytes = new byte[length];
    memoryStream.Read(imageBytes, 0, length);
}
```

Then parse the bytes to create a new image or whatever you need.

Comment: Hi Thanks a lot.. I was able to extract it but I had to make the code unsafe and then typecast the Integer into (byte*) before I can read it. But I have one issue with this - as below

Comment: The stream has a single page tiff image. When I write to a file I am able to see the image fine from file, but in consecutive loops as I read ans write the file gets fatter with more bytes written to it but it does not show as a multipage tif file. When I open it, it just shows the 1st page. Any ideas?

Comment: You cannot just write more pages to the same file to make it a multi page tiff. You will need to write them to separate files or find out how to modify the binary data and formatting to combine them.